# Add class when div is scrolled exactly half way in browser window, % not px

Tags: jquery, scroll

Using this code I can add a class to  divs when they get a certain amount of pixels from the top of the browser window. Is it possible to do this using % instead? so I can set it to be 50% from the top? This would mean a uniform effect on all screen sizes...

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.names').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+350) {
            $('.names').addClass("slideRight");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) like

```
$(document).height()
```

So, change your code to

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.names').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var halfWay = $(document).height()/2;
        if (imagePos < halfWay) {
            $('.names').addClass("slideRight");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This looks perfect thank you. I'l try it out later. Is there a way to get percentage? To achieve 40% for example?

Comment: @ScottEldo, yes. To do 40%, just multiply by 0.4 like $(document).height()*0.4

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use percentage or can you use half of the window height ?

```
$(window).height()/2;
```

Might look something like this:

```
if (imagePos < $(window).height()/2) {
    $('.names').addClass("slideRight");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to calculate the viewport height first:

```
var vpHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

Next you'll need to monitor when the DIV in question's vertical position relative to the viewport has reached the halfway point.

```
var vpPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect();
if (vpPosition.top <= vpHeight / 2) {
  //do something
}
```

Put the above in a `setInterval` so this repeats periodically, say every 100ms.

More info on getBoundingClientRect here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect